# How to make json valid which contains escape sequence and backslashes?

Tags: php, json

My angularjs formdata returns me a following json which is valid for now {mobile: "9898989889", otp: "5455"}

So when my PHP API receives it via $_POST, it looks like following

Array
(
[data] => {mobile: "9898989889", otp: "5455"}
)

So I need to convert it in json to put in my MySQL column with data type json.. So after using json encode, it returns me following

{"data":"{mobile: "9898989889", otp: "5455"}"}

which is invalid json due to double quotes and so I cant insert it in MySQL column.

Also, adding slashes to avoid escape sequence doesn't make sense as json containing slashes is again invalid and can not inserted in database.

Following is my PHP API code to insert json in database.

```
<?php

class userModel{
    
    function __construct(){
        $hostname = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = 'root1234';
        $dbname = 'website_automation';
        $this->con = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost');
    }

    public function addUser(){
        print_r($_POST);
        $dt = stripslashes(json_encode($_POST));

        $qry = "INSERT INTO users(data) VALUES ('".$dt."')";

        if($this->con->query($qry))
        {
            $this->generateResult('SUCCESS', 'Inserted_Successfully');
        }
        else
        { 
            $this->generateResult('FAILED', $this->con->error);
        }
    }

    private function generateResult($status='', $message='', $data='')
    {
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        if($data=='')
        {
            $responseArray = array($status => $message);
            echo json_encode($responseArray);
        }
        else
        {
            $responseArray = array("DATA"=>$data);
            echo json_encode($responseArray);
        }   
    }

}

?>
```

Please guide me in my issue.

Comment: Decode the value first and then encode it all. Something like: `$data = ['data' => json_decode($_POST['data'], true)];` and then store `json_encode($data);`. Now it shouldn't be double encoded.

Comment: You are currently _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. Never trust any data that you're not 100% in control of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The received string `{mobile: "9898989889", otp: "5455"}` is a string representation of a JavaScript object, it's not a JSON-formatted string.*

It's always best if apps communicate in a format that can both easily encode and decode, for instance JSON (or XML, or whichever widely-used format). So if you can update the Angular app to send you an actual JSON, that would be the best solution.

---

If it's not an option, you need to convert the stringified JavaScript object to something that PHP can understand, such as JSON.

Unfortunately, there are no native tools in PHP that could do that, but you can use a third-party library such as [js-object-to-json](https://packagist.org/packages/ovidigital/js-object-to-json).

It's pretty straigforward, as shown in their readme:

```
use Ovidigital\JsObjectToJson\JsConverter;

$jsObjectString = '{mobile: "9898989889", otp: "5455"}';
$json = JsConverter::convertToJson($jsObjectString);
```